# How to validate XML REST request in Springboot with Jaxb?

Tags: spring, rest, validation, xsd, jaxb

I thought this would be as easy as adding an annotation but I can't find a solution to this.

I have a simple endpoint that takes an XML request body:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/import", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Result> importReceipts(@Valid @RequestBody ImportRequest request) throws Exception {
```

Where ImportRequest is a JAXB class generated from an XSD. This works fine when a client sends a request, but if the request is not valid there is not error.

Please can anyone suggest the best way to validate this request body given the XSD?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929016/spring-validate-rest-controller-against-xsd-schema ? Creating a jaxb bean and adding schemas to it's configuration seems to solve the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Alex,

I saw this response earlier but I looked again at my code and spotted the error :)

```
@Bean
public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter()
{
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();

    marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
    marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());

    return marshallingHttpMessageConverter;
}

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller()
{
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setSchemas(new ClassPathResource("Import.xsd"), new ClassPathResource("BasicTypes.xsd"));
    jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Import.class);
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}
```

I had a typo but the main problem was I called jaxb2Marshaller.setSchemas more than once and the second call removed the first schemas.